How to add text background watermark to old .doc file using Apache POI in Java
How to add text background watermark to old .doc file using Apache POI in Java?
I'm working with Java and need to add text background watermark to legacy .doc (not .docx) file. Is it possible to achieve this using Apache POI?  If so, how can I implement it?
I'm looking for a solution that adds semi-transparent, diagonal text watermark across each page of the document.
Any code examples or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

See also How to add text watermarks to 80MB existed Excel files using Apache POI?

@trashgod Thank you for pointing that out. I'm the one who posted that question. I'm currently trying to solve watermark issues for different types of documents. Do you think some of the ideas or techniques could be applied to Word .doc files? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Have you considered creating a template in Microsoft Word then replacing tokens in the template? This way you don't need to do any formatting in POI, you can do it all via WYSIWYG. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-replace-pattern-word-document-doc-docx

@lance-java Thank you for your suggestion. The method using templates and token replacement is indeed an excellent solution. However, I'm dealing with existing .doc files with random content, rather than new documents based on fixed templates. The content and formatting of existing documents are unpredictable. Do you have any suggestions for this situation? Thank you again for your help and suggestions.

Have you considered adding the text background in MSWord then parsing the document with POI? Perhaps you could debug into the POI model to find the background configuration and reverse engineer a solution?

@lance-java Thank you for your follow-up suggestion.
